# Visual Studio Param comment doesn't show itself When Hover Mouse

Tags: visual-studio-2022

```
/// <summary>
/// summary is shown
/// </summary>
/// <param name="gridControl">but parameter discription is not shown</param>
/// <param name="xmlFileName">but parameter discription is not shown</param>
/// <param name="menuItem">but parameter discription is not shown</param>
/// <param name="folderName">but parameter discription is not shown</param>
public static void RestoreGrid_ColumnWidth_FromXml(GridControl gridControl, string xmlFileName, BaseMenu menuItem, string folderName = "BYEPC ColumnWidth")
{
    
}
```

As shown in the code i wrote summary comment above my method. When i hover my mouse upon the code (method name) i can only see the "summary" comment not the "param name = " comment. How can i make the param comment visible when i hover? please help..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPyly.png)

Comment: It is normal behavior, because comments show in context. When you hover any type or method - you see common information from summary tag. When you write parameters for this method you will see comment for current parameter from tag param.